# Display Dialog Framgment Where Tapped in Screen

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am working on android.I have some little problem to display dialog fragment in specific position.
Following is some information regarding my code.

I'm taking one Costume adapter for display data.in Adpater Layout i am having one image view and i want to display Dialog Fragment Exact left side of this image view When i Tapped in Image.So I'm Doing Following Code to get X and y Co-ordinate where I tapped in Screen.

```
 holder.img_Infoimage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


                //showDialog( holder.img_Infoimage.getX(), holder.img_Infoimage.getY());
                //int position = (int) v.getTag();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("X", (int) event.getX());
                bundle.putInt("Y", (int) event.getY());
               //bundle.putInt("X", holder.img_Infoimage.getLeft());
                //bundle.putInt("Y", holder.img_Infoimage.getTop());


                //  bundle.putInt("X", (int) holder.img_Infoimage.getLeft());
                //  bundle.putInt("Y", (int) holder.img_Infoimage.getTop());

                 Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), ":::::: position x ::::" +event.getX());
                  Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), ":::::: position Y ::::" + event.getY());

                InfoAlertDialog alertDialog = new InfoAlertDialog();
                alertDialog.setArguments(bundle);
                alertDialog.show(fragmentManager, NearByFriendsFragment.class.getName());

            }
            return true;


        }
    });
```

And I am Also having on InfoAlertDialog class which is extends by DialogFragment.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
   /*wmlp.x = 422;   //x position
    wmlp.y = 49;*/   //y position


    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    getDialog().setCancelable(true);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    //Log.e("", "X :::::::" + wmlp.x + " Y:::::" + wmlp.y);

    wmlp.x = bundle.getInt("X");   //x position
    wmlp.y = bundle.getInt("Y");   //y position


    /*
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    wmlp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    wmlp.height=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    wmlp.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE;
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = bundle.getInt("X");   //x position
    wmlp.y = bundle.getInt("Y");   //y position
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
    wmlp.y = 500;
    */
    Log.e("", "X :::::::" + wmlp.x + " Y:::::" + wmlp.y);
    //getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_info_alert, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

in All Above code we can have some Comment it's Just for your Reference because i also try this but it's not display dialog at any specific position.

Please anyone can tell me how can i fix it...?

Comment: whats your requirement??

Comment: I want to just display Dialog Exact left side of my image view where i Tapped.I also mention in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). It's a lot more flexible than a Dialog in cases like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I Really try hard to solve this problem and Finally I got solution of this problem.I am share this code with you.

Just making following change in my code.

First Pass Listview in Constructor of Adapter.

```
 int xCoordinates,yCoordinates;
ListView lv;


public NearByFriendsAdapter(Context context, List<NearByFriendsSupportClass> list, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ListView lst_NearByFriends) {
    super(context, 0,list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
    this.lv=lst_NearByFriends;
}
```

and Also taking Two Seperate event to get X and Y co-ordinate of your screen and Display Dialog Like Following.

```
 holder.img_Infoimage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
            lv.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
            int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
            int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];

            //xCoordinates=x-1500;
            yCoordinates=y-490;
            return false;
        }
    });

    holder.img_Infoimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            //bundle.putInt("X", xCoordinates);
            bundle.putInt("Y", yCoordinates);

            InfoAlertDialog alertDialog=new InfoAlertDialog();
            alertDialog.setArguments(bundle);
            alertDialog.show(fragmentManager, NearByFriendsFragment.class.getName());


        }
    });
```

And Also making Following change in AlertDialog

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    getDialog().setCancelable(true);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    wmlp.y = bundle.getInt("Y");
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_info_alert,container,false);
    Log.e("", "X :::::::" + wmlp.x + " Y:::::" + wmlp.y);

    return view;
}
```

Thanks,
I hope it's Help full to you.